# Prevent from auto fill form data

Tags: php, jquery, html, wordpress, autocomplete

I am facing a problem related to auto fill in form.
Actually i am running a trust charity website which collects fund from donor.

**Problem :**

When i have entered a donation for one cause and again i want to enter donation for the same cause but with different credit card detail. 
then i am strange the form where i need to enter detail card related is retained all of the information from the previous donation so everything was entered.

I have tried  `autocomplete="off"` in form and also in input.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a unique identifier to the beginning or end of the id's or names of the form elements.

Alternatively there is this:

> autocomplete = ”off” is not valid markup with XHTML Transitional,
>   which is a common DOCTYPE.Use this to keep a valid markup
>   from

```
if (document.getElementsByTagName) {

    var inputElements = document.getElementsByTagName(“input”);

    for (i = 0; inputElements[i]; i++) {

        if (inputElements[i].className && (inputElements[i].className.indexOf(“disableAutoComplete”) != -1)) {

            inputElements[i].setAttribute(“autocomplete”, ”off”);

        }

    }

}
```

From http://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/autocomplete-off/

Comment: @John like the example below

Answer (score 1):

rename the input for each pageload. generate a prefix, and put it in a hidden field in the form.

```
$prefix = date("U"); //lets use unix time for this.
```

...

```
<input type="hidden" name="prefix" value="<?php echo $prefix; ?>"/>
<input type="text"   name="<?php echo $prefix; ?>_cardnumber" />
```

...

And when processing look for

```
$_POST[$_POST['prefix'].'_cardnumber']
```

Answer (score 1):

If this is Google Chrome then it actually has a feature which ignores autocomplete settings from the current web form and will actually pull data from it's own "personal program cache" and populate the fields for you as a convenience. It also does this when it recognizes address fields. Thomas Martin Klein's answer will probably work best but I have not tested it before so Chrome may be smart enough to recognize your algorithm anyways. Good luck!